# close two modals at same time (modal inside a modal)

Tags: javascript, angular, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, user-experience

I have a View/Edit button in my angular application which shows the details of user in a modal when clicked In modal it has Save and delete buttons. When they click on delete button the user will be deleted. Before they delete, I want to show a delete confirmation.

So, I'm showing the delete confirmation modal inside the first modal.

Now, I want to dismiss the two modals when they click on final delete button. I tried using
 `data-dismiss= "modal"` so that the modal closes automatically, but this is closing only the second modal which is above the first modal. How would I close both modals at a time?

And also I feel that this is not a good idea to have 2 modals like this. Is there any alternative to this?

Thanks!

**Please let me know if any code or more information is needed**

Comment: If closing all modals will work, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17978043/how-to-close-all-active-bootstrap-modals-on-session-timeout

Comment: the `hide.bs.modal` should propagate, unless stopped, so bind latest modal `hide.bs.modal` to hide both.

Comment: I'm using bootstrap modals in angular 4. I must have mentioned this before.